# Is it possible to access multiple interfaces in a dictionary of one interface?

Tags: c#, interface, multiple-inheritance

First off: Sorry if the question is oddly phrased. I'm new to multiclassing in C#, and I am somewhat stuck.

I am currently making an inventory system that uses one dictionary for all the items. The items themselves are of different classes, and use interfaces for properties. Let's say that these are the interfaces, for simplicity. One interface has the name, the second has a specific value, and the third has yet another specific value.

I can't seem to figure out how (if possible) I can access properties of the second interface, as the only suggestions I get are those of the itemtype used in the dictionary.

```
// the interface examples
interface IStandardProperties
{
   string Name { get; set; } 
}

interface IItemType1
{ 
    int SomeValue { get; set; } 
}

interface IItemType2
{ 
    int AnotherValue { get; set; } 
}

// Then we have two classes that uses these. 
class ItemType1 : IStandardProperties, IItemType1
{ 
    public string Name; 
    public int SomeValue;
    public ItemType1() 
    {
       this.Name = "Item type 1"; this.SomeValue = "10";
    }
}

class ItemType2 : IStandardProperties, IItemtype2
{
    public string Name; 
    public int SomeValue;
    public ItemType1() 
    { 
        this.Name = "Item type 1"; 
        this.AnotherValue = "100";
    }
}

// and finally the dictionary in question.

Dictionary<int, IStandardProperties> items = New Dictionary<int, IStandardProperties>();
```

Now, both these items can be stored in the dictionary, however I can't seem to figure out how (or if it's possible) to access the value stored in the interface properties of SomeValue and AnotherValue through the dictionary. I have seen a couple of examples where "as InterfaceName" is used, but I am uncertain of the useage of this.

Is there a way of accessing these? (*and in case I am just horribly mistaken about interfaces, are these values even stored in the dictionary?*)

I am not in any way an expert, so I would love any corrections or assistance you could provide in this matter.

Comment: You can check manually using `is` - `if(items[1] is IItemType1 itemType1) { Console.WriteLine( itemType1.SomeValue )  }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you create a `Dictionary<int, IStandardProperties>`, the only thing we know for sure is that **every** item implements that specific interface.

If you were to ask the `AnotherValue` property of an item of type `ItemType1`, you would obviously not be doing something that's right. This is why your dictionary items cannot show this property: *they are not properties of each and every element of your dictionary*.

A way you could achieve what you want is type check:

```
if (items[0] is IItemType1) {
    (items[0] as IItemType1).SomeValue ... 
} 
if (items[0] is IItemType2) {
    (items[0] as IItemType2).AnotherValue ... 
}
```

This will check if the item implements said interface, and only then access the member (property) of that interface

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly your question, this line

```
class ItemType1 : IStandardProperties, IItemType1
```

declares `ItemType1` as implementing `IStandardProperties` and `IItemType1`, which means that it has *both* traits.

Your dicationary declaration

```
Dictionary<int, IStandardProperties> items = New Dictionary<int, IStandardProperties>();
```

says that your dictionary is typed from `int` to `IStandardProperties`. Which means that the value of the dictionary is **known** and **enforced** to be of type `IStandardProperties`.
However, this does not tell about how possible traits of your value.

Therefore, you have to ask for specific trait when you need it (note, as of C# 7 there are shortcuts, which I avoided on purpose):

```
IStandardProperties v; 
if (items.TryGetValue("key", out v))
{
    // found. the line below asks if the interface is supported
    var item1 = v as IItemType1;
    if (item1 != null)
    {
        // v supports IItemType1, therefore you can do something with it, by using item1
    }

    // we repeat for IItemType2
    var item2 = v as IItemType2;
    if (item2 != null)
    {
        // v supports IItemType2, therefore you can do something with it, by using item2
    }

}
else
{
    // not found
}
```